# Side Adbanner scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar, banner

I have a fixed width website (`1000px` for example) and I'm considering adding a side banner (`120px` width for example)

What I need is for the banner to *not* add scrollbars. E.g. If a visitor has `1024x768`, I don't want the ad banner to add a horizontal scrollbar.  If their screen size is wider than content+banner, then of course there is no problem.

Is it achieveable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with css:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This will remove horizontal scrollbar of the page even if the viewport is smaller than the content.

Comment: Thanks but is there any non-CSS3 solution?

Comment: Just for hiding the horizontal scrollbar no. Nevertheless, the property `overflow-x` is supported by IE7+, Chrome 2+, FF2+, Safari 3+... so basically pretty much every one (too bad for the 2% still using IE6)